# angular http callback function

Tags: angular, typescript

I just wonder what is the equivalent for the promise in response object. For example, how can I write the below code in typescript?

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I have included an example of how to handle async code with angular. I usually set up an http service file for the actual crud operations. Then, in the angular component, I call the right method in the service file, and pass it any parameters needed.

In angular component

```
  searchVendor(vendorStr) {
    if (!vendorStr) vendorStr = '';
    this.httpService.searchVendors(vendorStr).subscribe(results => {
      this.vendorSearchResults = results;
    });
  }
```

In http.ts

```
 searchVendors(vendorStr) {
    // console.log(vendorStr);
    return this.httpClient.get<Vendor[]>(
      `${baseUrl}/v2/vendor/searchVendor/?searchStr=${vendorStr}`,
    );
  }
```